# How do I make alert print over 50, under 50 (if statement)?

Tags: javascript

```
function randomise(){
    var ran_number=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    return ran_number;
    return(ran_number);
}
```

I would like an if statement to be something like below.

```
alert(randomise + "You scored over 50, You win");
alert(randomise + "You scored under 50, You lose");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: There are some issues with your randomise function

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = randomise();
if (value > 50)
  alert(value + " You scored over 50, You win");
else
  alert(value + " You scored under 50, You lose");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ran_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

if(ran_number > 50){
  alert(ran_number+"  You scored over 50, You win");
}else{
  alert(ran_number+"  You scored under 50, You lose");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue on [Geoffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668037/6201440) - without declaring a variable:

```
function randomise(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

if( (i = randomise()) > 50 ) {
    alert('You scored '+i+', you win!'); 
} else {
    alert('You scored '+i+', you lose...'); 
}
```

And I'm gonna leave this here for the kids to learn the magic of Javascript:

```
if( (i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)) > 50 ) { alert('You scored '+i+', you win!'); } 
else { alert('You scored '+i+', you lose...'); }
```

And with a button to tell you how well you did:

```js
document.getElementById('buttown').onclick = function(){
  if( (i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)) > 50 ) { alert('You scored '+i+', you win!'); } 
  else { alert('You scored '+i+', you lose...'); }
};
```

```html
<button id="buttown">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i make this load from a button? and not when i run the page.